# Shrink/Reduce disk size on a Linux RAID 1 server

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

i am looking for a way to clone my HDD to SSD without loosing data or the Linux system itself. The problem is the size of current HDD is 1TB and the SSD we got have 480GB, so i can't clone directly cause the disk size differ, but i know the disk is not fully used so i guess this could be shrinked with an external tool or via command line on the server. Now I have 2 HDD 1 TB each connected to the server and don't know how to replace with these smaller and faster SSD. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
#lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   931G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   953M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0   953M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 929.1G  0 part 
  ├─rl-root           253:0    0  18.6G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rl-swap           253:1    0  29.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─rl-usr            253:2    0    10G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─rl-var_lib_docker 253:3    0  93.1G  0 lvm  /var/lib/docker
  ├─rl-opt            253:4    0  93.1G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─rl-var_log_audit  253:5    0   4.7G  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─rl-var            253:6    0   9.3G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─rl-home           253:7    0   1.9G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─rl-var_log        253:8    0   4.7G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─rl-tmp            253:9    0   4.7G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─rl-var_tmp        253:10   0   4.7G  0 lvm  /var/tmp

# fdisk -l /dev/sd?
Disk /dev/sda: 931 GiB, 999653638144 bytes, 1952448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0219246B-336B-4D22-96A3-FD679EDA66DE

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1953791    1951744   953M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1953792    3905535    1951744   953M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3905536 1952448478 1948542943 929.1G Linux LVM

# df -h | grep -v docker
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                       7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          7.5G   95M  7.5G   2% /run
tmpfs                          7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rl-root             19G  232M   19G   2% /
/dev/mapper/rl-usr              10G  4.8G  5.3G  48% /usr
/dev/mapper/rl-tmp             4.7G   99M  4.6G   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rl-home            1.9G 1014M  885M  54% /home
/dev/mapper/rl-var             9.4G  3.0G  6.4G  32% /var
/dev/sda2                      949M  276M  674M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                      952M  5.8M  946M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rl-var_tmp         4.7G   66M  4.6G   2% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/rl-var_log         4.7G  1.3G  3.5G  27% /var/log
/dev/mapper/rl-opt              94G  7.6G   86G   9% /opt
/dev/mapper/rl-var_log_audit   4.7G  106M  4.6G   3% /var/log/audit
tmpfs                          1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/user/0

# lshw
*-raid
                description: RAID bus controller
                product: MegaRAID SAS-3 3008 [Fury]
                vendor: Broadcom / LSI
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: scsi0
                version: 02
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: raid pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=megaraid_sas latency=0
                resources: irq:17 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:91c00000-91c0ffff memory:91b00000-91bfffff memory:91a00000-91afffff
              *-disk
                   description: SCSI Disk
                   product: PRAID CP400i
                   vendor: FTS
                   physical id: 2.0.0
                   bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0
                   logical name: /dev/sda
                   version: 4.68
                   serial: 004f93e10b84d6222c40f6200004000e
                   size: 931GiB (999GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=0219246b-336b-4d22-96a3-fd679eda66de logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
                 *-volume:0
                      description: Windows FAT volume
                      vendor: mkfs.fat
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0,1
                      logical name: /dev/sda1
                      logical name: /boot/efi
                      version: FAT32
                      serial: cbe6-07f6
                      size: 951MiB
                      capacity: 952MiB
                      capabilities: boot fat initialized
                      configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
                 *-volume:1
                      description: EFI partition
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0,2
                      logical name: /dev/sda2
                      logical name: /boot
                      serial: 7ca4eedb-7995-4a39-b1c8-676c006e7c83
                      capacity: 952MiB
                      configuration: mount.fstype=xfs mount.options=rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,sunit=128,swidth=128,noquota state=mounted
                 *-volume:2
                      description: LVM Physical Volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0,3
                      logical name: /dev/sda3
                      serial: gE8t7L-MEtM-wxjh-VGNz-19ch-dDXX-NQKV7n
                      size: 269GiB
                      capacity: 929GiB
                      capabilities: multi lvm2

# lspci | grep RAID
02:00.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3008 [Fury] (rev 02)
```

@Nikita i have access to this physically but also web, think RAID config is software.

Comment: Please, **show** the actual layout you have, instead of describing it. Just add `lsblk` output [into your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1151785/edit). Also explain, is there a requirement to do it online, can you connect all four devices at once, what kind of RAID it is (software, hardware; if so, which one)? If you can and allowed to boot the system from some live media while all four devices are connected, that would be the simplest case.

Comment: If you use EXT4 as filesystem you can use command `resize2fs`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/780284/shrinking-ext4-partition-on-command-line

Comment: While the layout itself is very good and indeed the simplest to work with, the RAID doesn't look like software. You have a single /dev/sdX device, that is either the single physical media or a hardware RAID volume which is designed to look like a single physical media. The size 999653638144 = 931GiB **exactly** strongly hints at HW RAID with *coercion size* set to 1 GiB. Show `lspci`, please, to be sure. To provide more complete instructions, I need to know which RAID card is there, so what program to use and how to use it to create another RAID from another set of media.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `lspci | grep RAID` to filter out unnecessary garbage. Also, show `df -h`, please. And, lshw and fdisk are redundant, better be safely removed for brevity. (Maybe, leave `fdisk -l /dev/sda` there, it's slightly helpful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the system which was built with possible rearrangements in mind, this could be as easy as connect other devices, initialize them, migrate volumes and reinstall the boot loader, and that might be even achievable without bringing services down.

I have good news for you: your layout matches that. You use LVM not all the space in the volume group is allocated. All logical volumes together seem to occupy less than the space that is typically available on the 480GB SSD, which means you don't need any filesystem resizes. I think everything is possible to do even without service stopping.

Also, while not related to this particular case, good to remember that it doesn't always boils down to shrinking the file systems and then cloning. In many cases you may just create new file systems and copy files.

---

You have a Broadcom HW RAID, commonly known as a "LSI MegaRAID SAS", a modern one, which is managed with [the `storcli` program](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/storage-and-ethernet-connectivity/enterprise-storage-solutions/storcli-12gbs-megaraid-tri-mode/1-0/v11869215/v11673442.html). To obtain it from the Broadcom website you need to know what card model it is; for now, we know it's using a 3008 controller chip, which is unfortunately not enough to direct you to the genuine download page.

The utility will allow you to manipulate and monitor your RAID from within the OS; **this ability is a must**! However, I don't have enough experience working with it; I used to have `megacli`, which is nowadays obsolete and probably it's not very a good idea to use it with your newer card. Alternatively, you can reboot and invoke the boot-time utility using some keystroke, and create new logical disk from there.

After creating the new RAID array and new logical disk from your new set of media, you need to partition it like this one and create the similar layout, with just the last partition smaller.

If you're using a remote connection to perform migration, I suggest to do all the operations in the `screen` or `tmux`, so even if you happen to lose a connection due to networking problems, the shell session will remain and you'll be able to connect to it. If you're sitting at the terminal or use some king of KVM (iLO, iDRAC, xClarity, etc.), this is not important.

Let's assume the new RAID virtual disk is happened to be called `/dev/sdb` in the OS. **Make sure you use the right device, else it'll be hard to recover your data.**:

1. Run `fdisk /dev/sdb`
2. Press `g` to create GPT partition table (and agree with erasing).
3. Create EFI System Partition (ESP) by creating a new partition of same size: `n`, select type 1 "ESP" and use size `953M` (M means MiB, that is exact size of your existing ESP)
4. Create boot partition: `n`, select "Linux filesystem" (I don't remember which number it corresponds to) and use size `953M` again.
5. Create LVM partition: `n`, select "Linux LVM" (31 if I am not mistaken) and to fill all the remaining space accept whatever it suggests.
6. Accept changed and quit: `w`.

Then, clone filesystems that aren't LVM. For that:

6. Unmount ESP and /boot partitions: `umount /boot/efi /boot`
7. Clone their contents: `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1` and `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb2`. If there are errors on this stage, don't proceed until you resolved them! One cause might be sizes are incorrect.
8. Since you're using XFS for /boot, you have to change UUID for of the clone now, else you won't be able to mount: `xfs_admin -U generate /dev/sdb2`. Don't forget to update `/etc/fstab` with the new UUID (if it uses UUIDs to mount, which it should).
9. Mount new /boot and ESP partitions: `mount /dev/sdb2 /boot` and `mount /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi`.

Now, create PV out of the remaining large partition and add it into the existing volume group:

10. `pvcreate /dev/sdb3`
11. `vgextend r1 /dev/sdb3`

Now prepare for the longest operation: move data off the HDD physical volume:

12. `pvmove -vi 5 /dev/sda3`

Lastly, remove HDD logical drive from the volume group and remove LVM labels:

13. `vgreduce r1 /dev/sda3`
14. `pvremove /dev/sda3`

When it finishes, it's time to reconfigure to boot from the new RAID. You may need to set up your RAID card to make this new volume to be primary boot; that's commonly non needed for EFI boot, but won't hurt so do it.

Set up firmware boot entry to boot from the new RAID. Use tool provided by your OS release, or do it manually with `efibootmgr`; in any case, concrete commands depend on what distro you are using.

Comment: Thanks very helpfull.